# Wordpress query_posts() with an array?

Tags: php, wordpress, arrays

I'm trying to query posts based on a number of ID's that are contained in an array.

My array (called $my_array) looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 108
    [1] => 129
    [2] => 145
)
```

And my Query looks like this:

```
<?php query_posts(array('post__in' => $my_array)); ?>
```

However this just returns one post, the post has the ID of the first item in the array (108).

Do I have my syntax wrong?

Comment: note that you can use post_type => 'any' if you have a range of ids over multiple post types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'page',//or whatever type
  'post__in' => array(108,129,145)
  );
query_posts($args);
```

or

```
$arr=array(108,129,145);
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'post__in' => $arr
  );
query_posts($args);
```

Comment: is it possible to re-order the posts or are we stuck with the order of the array (which seem to be the case with what I'm working on)

Answer (score 2):

You always have to set the `post_type` with the `post__in` argument. So your line should look like the following:

```
<?php query_posts(array('post_type' => 'post', 'post__in' => $my_array)); ?>
```

That will query the posts with the IDs you have in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, 
I am posting an answer, although you probably found it. I don't have reputation yet to post comments, query_posts supports all the arguments from WP_Query including ordering you can add 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' to the query_posts call